# Golang invalid memory address crashes the dotnet application

Tags: c#, go, interop

I running some go code from a dotnet application and I'm fiddling with the defer in go (I try to force different type of crashes).
I have one case, an invalid memory access, where the the panic actually crashes the whole dotnet application (on Windows 10 not on Linux). Can't figure out if I'm missing something.

Note: If I force an "integer divide by zero" or a "panic()" it doesn't crash the dotnet application.

The below samples are execute in Windows 10:

```
package main
import "C"
import "fmt"

type HelloFunc func(string)
//export Hello
func Hello() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("defer start")
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("hello from the deferred function!")
        }
        fmt.Println("defer end")
    }()

    fmt.Println("Hello")
    var hf HelloFunc
    hf("world")
    fmt.Println("don't print me")
}

func main() {
    Hello()
}
```

Build the DLL (Cross compiled on a Linux system)

```
env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ go build -o test.dll -i -v -buildmode=c-shared test.go
```

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace native_lib
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-->> 1");
            try {
                GoFunctions.Hello();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine($"-->> {e}");
            } finally {
                Console.WriteLine("-->> 2");
            }
        }
    }
}
static class GoFunctions
{
    [DllImport("./test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void Hello();
}
```

The output:

```
> dotnet run
-->> 1
Hello
> echo $?
False
```

Comment: `hf` is not initialized, just declared so it has a zero value which is `nil` for funcs. You're attempting to call a `nil` function which is clearly invalid. The short version is basically this: https://play.golang.org/p/pyqKMBeH46T. The defer works because it calls recover and catches the panic: https://play.golang.org/p/qn8cPXkeAeL

Comment: Yes it's a forced crash with an invalid memory pointer. The defer actually works fine when I run the exe file (just the go code). When I executes the C# that invokes the dll (go code) it crashes hard. No trace of defer at all.

Comment: Ok, so please remove the entire second half of the questions, it doesn't matter. Maybe add some debugging statements to make sure the Go code gets executed at all. And see if you can get more debugging info such as stack traces.

Comment: Thanks, good point, made an update with some more debug logs. The defer make no life signs at all when invoked from C# (for this particular case)